# How can I put two data in string in model class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have these in my model class:

```cs
public string City { get; set; }
public string ZipCode { get; set; }
```

But I want to get it together as well. I tried doing something like this:

```cs
[DisplayFormat(City, Zipcode)]
public string CityZipCode { get; set; }
```

But that didn't work but maybe you get the idea of what I'm meaning. How can I get these together?

Please help me if you can, thanks!

Comment: `public string CityZipCode => $"{City}, {ZipCode}";` for example. Though you may want to do that in your view instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a property that generates what you want on the fly using the other properties. The advantage of this is that you don't actually need to store the combined string until you need it.

```
public string CityZipCode => $"{City}, {ZipCode}";
```

Comment: Downside is that you are creating a new string...

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, but only if it's needed. Plus, that seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: Yes, I mean a new string object in memory. Whereas just outputting it to the view as separate strings won't do that.

Comment: @DavidG: Yes, sure. But the OP seems to want the class to provide it.

Comment: Thanks! Awesome, that worked!

Comment: But just giving code without explaining a better way is negligent as a senior developer.

Comment: @DavidG: I do things like this sometimes. The class knows best what internal logic is required. Also, it might include special handling for nulls, etc. I'm not convinced doing it manually in the view is always a better way.

Comment: /you are missing my point. Perhaps doing it in the model is better, I don't know, but we need to give new inexperienced devs the tools to figure these things out for themselves. So a code dump answer without explanation, while correct, isn't helpful in the long term.